# Sending HTML E-mails with Attachment for Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345032/how-to-send-a-simple-email-programatically-exists-a-simple-way-to-do-it) but Eclipse still cant resolve "Attachment" and "DataService".

I've imported mail.jar and activation.jar, what could I be doing wrong? I've tried countless other sending email solutions on SO/Google but I couldn't get any of them to work with my attachment and send HTML emails.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [this tutorial](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android) and changed

```
    messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
```

to

```
    messageBodyPart.setContent(_body, "text/html");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to construct email to be sent by user manually (open his mail program with new email and attachment) you can use this code:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" ));
emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "SUBJECT");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "MESSAGE");
File toAttach = new File("/path/to/your/file");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(toAttach);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Comment: I wanted to send it programmatically without Intents

Comment: Sorry, seems I didn't remove all project-specific info from snippet, replace it with `toAttach`