# Sending email without user interaction works fine, but

Tags: android, email, gmail, jakarta-mail

I followed the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345032/how-to-send-a-simple-email-programatically-exists-a-simple-way-to-do-it) and have an order confirmation mail send in the background just fine. I created a new G-Mail account, so even if they end up hacking that account it's not the end of the world, since it's only used to send an email to me and the actual user.

The problem is, more or less once a week I get the notification from gmail that somebody unauthorized tried to login into my account. I can accept the activity (login), mail through the Android App and it works for a little while.

But this is not ideal. Is there a better way to handle this or a less protected mail service available? I tried my own domain, but somehow it's not working since my mobile provider's ip range is on black lists.

Comment: Why would you want do this? It's way better to have your App call your website. Setup a small PHP script which accepts the request and generates the mail from your Webserver. This way the account data is not exposed.

Comment: Thanks Tseng, I never thought of that!

Answer (score 0):

I used the following snippet:

```
<? 
    //change this to your email. 
    $to = "to@email.com"; 
    $from = "from@yourdomain.com"; 
    $subject = "PHP Test Mail"; 

    //begin of HTML message 
    $message = "<html> 
  <body bgcolor=\"#DCEEFC\"> 
    <center> 
        <b>I am reciving HTML email......</b> <br> 
        <font color=\"red\">Thanks!</font> <br> 
        <a href=\"http://www.stackoverflow.com/\">* StackOverFlow</a> 
    </center> 
      <br><br>*** Now you Can send HTML Email <br> 
  </body> 
</html>"; 
   //end of message 

    // To send the HTML mail we need to set the Content-type header. 
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0rn"; 
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1rn"; 
    $headers  .= "From: $from\r\n"; 
    //options to send to cc+bcc 
    //$headers .= "Cc: [email]cc@email.com[/email]"; 
    //$headers .= "Bcc: [email]bcc@email.com[/email]"; 

    // now lets send the email. 
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 

    echo "Message has been sent....!"; 
?>
```