# send email from android app issue with subject and bcc

Tags: android

hello i am trying to send an email from an android application , the below code is working fine  since it is opening the email app configured on the phone but the problem is it is not taking the subject and the Bcc any ideas

```
send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ address.getText().toString()});
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject.getText());
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailBody.getText());
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC, CC.getText());
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
    }
});
```

Comment: Plz refer this, it might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4345084/1554935

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the getting the address you got the text by **.getText();** then you made it a string for other uses, because it was an editable text from **editText**. But in the other **EditTextss** you forgot to add **.toString();** so you can use it as a string in email.

try this:

```
send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("plain/text");

        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ address.getText().toString()});
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject.getText().toString());
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailBody.getText().toString());
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC, CC.getText().toString());

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
    }
});
```

please ask if you didn't understand

Comment: are you sure about the **.EXTRA_BCC** & the ediText **CC.** ?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ address.getText().toString()});
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject.getText().toString());
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailBody.getText().toString());
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC, CC.getText().toString());
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
    }
});
```

EditText.getText() return a editable you need to change it to String by applying toString();

Answer (score 0):

**Will work 100%**

```
String[] to = value.toString().split(",");
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("text/html");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, "array of bcc like to");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, String.format(getString(R.string.share_email_subject), IN_SHARE_CAPTION));
        i.putExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                Html.fromHtml(IjoomerUtilities.prepareEmailBody(message == null ? "" : message, getSmartApplication().readSharedPreferences().getString(SP_USERNAME, "") + " " + getString(R.string.saw_this_story_on_the) + " "
                        + getString(R.string.app_name) + " " + getString(R.string.thought_you_should_see_it), IN_SHARE_CAPTION, IN_SHARE_DESCRIPTION, IN_SHARE_SHARELINK, getString(R.string.try_ijoomeradvance), getString(R.string.site_url))));
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
            finish();
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            ting(getString(R.string.share_email_no_client));
        }
```