# Auto sending email for mobile app

Tags: java, android

I have developed an android app and almost done with it, but I'm stuck with the mail option. I want to set an auto send option for my mail, through which it sends an email by the end of the day. Can anyone please give me a hint or link of any example for that kind of coding.

Comment: try this link https://github.com/kristijandraca/BackgroundMailLibrary

Comment: For simple mail from application please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a

Answer (score 0):

Check the following link for sending the email [How to send a simple email programatically? (exists a simple way to do it??)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345032/how-to-send-a-simple-email-programatically-exists-a-simple-way-to-do-it)

And schedule an alarm using AlarmManager to fire at the end of the day and there you can send the mail...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look into the JavaMail API - there are also a number of similar questions here on SO to get you started:

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-ap/2033124#2033124)