# Send a mail through an android app

Tags: android, email

I've implemented a class that can send a mail. However, you can only write a topic and the message and when you click on "Send" you've to choose which app (Outlook or Gmail) you want to send the mail with and then write your e-mail. However, I want to make it possible for the user to send a mail directly from the my app instead of using another app. So I want to make it possible for the user to write his/her e-mail/gmail and message and then send the message to my e-mail. So in other words in the fragment I want an `EditText` where the user writes his/her e-mail/gmail, another `EditText` where the user writes the message and a button to send. How can this be implemented?

This is what I have done in my app to send a mail:

```
   private void sendemail(String message) {
        String [] reciever = new String[]{"myemail@hotmail.com"};
        String subject = ("Feedback/Question");
        Intent mailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, reciever);
        mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        mailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mailIntent, "Choose an application to send your mail with"));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this library -> [Send email in background](https://github.com/yesidlazaro/GmailBackground). It will send an email from your app without users interaction.

Cheers!

Comment: It seems to me that the user needs to sign in with a Gmail account and then send the mail? What about hotmail? Isn't possible to make it send without signing in?

Answer (score 0):

using java mailApi,you must have to authenticate gmail app using credential.
please check this link:

[Email via Java MailAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124)

other link to provide custom class to send mail programatically.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4345084/1223291

I hope its useful to you.

Comment: As I understand, the user needs to write his/her password in order to send a mail. Does this also support hotmail/live ?

Comment: may be.i have not implemented it.so not clearly .but may be its work.othewise 2nd option is best.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method....

```
public void sendEmail()
{

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

intent.setType("message/rfc822");

 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"care@xyz.com"});

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "care Feedback");

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));

}
```

Comment: In this piece of code, what is needed? Only the sender's mail and message? If so, where do I write me as receiver?

Comment: Write your email where care@xyz.com is written and use this method where you want.

Comment: Dear, this method does the same as mine.... It uses a native app, and I want it to send directly from the app